# What does this.$ mean in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, this

What does this.$ mean in Angular?

I see cases where 'this' is set to a variable such as var vm = this;

Then vm is used like vm.$.Something ..

What does the vm.$ mean?

This is a classy angular example:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate','angular-growl', 'classy']);

app.classy.controller({

  name: 'TodoController',

  inject: ['$scope', 'growl', 'todoStorage'],

  data: {
    items: 'todoStorage.get()'
  },

  init: function() {
    this._resetTodoEntry();
  },

  watch: {
    '{object}items': '_onTodoChange'
  },

  methods: {

    _getRemaining: 'items | filter:{ completed: false }',

    _onTodoChange: function() {
      this.$.remainingCount = this._getRemaining().length;
      this.todoStorage.put(this.items);
    },
```

Comment: Please add the code snippet where this has been used.

Answer (score 3):

It refer to $scope (classy)

> Accessing $scope and dependencies     Dependencies are available using
>   this.DependencyName.     To access the $scope You can simply write
>   this.$.foo = 'bar'; instead of     this.$scope.foo = 'bar';. Although
>   you can use still use this.$scope if you prefer.

http://davej.github.io/angular-classy/